# Is possible to detect at preprocessor-time if a type is defined in C++?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

Look like in some point of the GCC history, the type `ulong` is defined as `unsigned long long`, but this is creating some conflicts between compilers because i pass the project to others with compilers that do not have `ulong` defined (like Visual C++). This is an example of what i would like to do:

```
#ifndef ulong
typedef unsigned long long ulong;
#endif
```

But this is never going to work because that is not the way `#ifdef` works. How would you do it? How to do it in the shortest way?

Comment: You can use conditionally define `ulong` when building with other compilers.

Comment: @Mansoor yes, is going to be longer but is the best solution right now

Comment: Only barely relevant, but Windows also defines `typedef unsigned __int64 ULONGLONG;` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/c57d9fba-12ef-4853-b0d5-a6f472b50388

Comment: What's wrong with using `std::uint64_t` from [`cstdint`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint)?

Comment: @chtz type 10 times `ulong` and 10 times `uint64_t` and you will notice it. But is also a solution (Stockfish uses it)

Answer (score 1):

For your problem, you can just write `typedef unsigned long ulong;` without any preprocessing, since you are allowed to repeat typedefs (In any C++, but only C11 onwards if you are using C).

I would suggest not using `ulong` in your code at all, since it is just provided for compatibility with some systems, and is not standard C nor C++. `unsigned long` is easier to understand and not much harder to write

For reference, it's defined in `<sys/types.h>` (as `unsigned long` and not `unsigned long long`, but these can be the same size)

Comment: The only problem that we get here is that `unsigned long` is different in 32 bits applications than in 64 bits applications, and you may want the "big" version.(But you know what? is it not very likely that someone will use x32 compilers this days, and we can be sure if the final user is trying to compile with a 32 bit compiler). So, very good solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible for the preprocessor  to determine whether a type (or anything else, other than a preprocessor macro) has been defined. The preprocessor runs before any of that has happened, after all.

If you want your code to be portable across computers, do not use compiler-specific  facilities which are not part of the C++ standard.

Comment: Well, in that case i have to go to the GCC developers team with my torch and my trident because i use to define by myself `ulong` everytime, but the fact that they define it complicates it

Comment: So add some definitions based on which compiler is being used...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking for a type, check for compilers.

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
typedef unsigned long long ulong;
#endif
```

or `#if _MSC_VER >= 1910` for checking minimal version.

Other compilers usually have their own specific defines, or simply provide your own define depending on compiler type.

Answer (score 0):

Well, seen that:

- Visual C++ does not define `ulong`
- GCC defines it since GCC 6
- The last applies to Clang to
- Clang defines `__GNUC__` as 4 in Clang 6

the best way is to add this code:

```
#if _MSC_VER || (__GNUC__ && __GNUC__ < 6 && !__clang__) || (__clang__ && __clang_major__ < 6)
typedef unsigned long long ulong;
#endif
```

And is going to work in most of the cases, BUT, this still can fail if someone is using GCC 4 with GCC 6+ libraries or something like that.